# Why exponential enum keys are used here?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parsing, compilation

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/964565e06968259fc4e6de6f1e88ab5e0663a94a/lib/typescript.d.ts#L390) you can find this code:

```
enum NodeFlags {
    None = 0,
    Let = 1,
    Const = 2,
    NestedNamespace = 4,
    Synthesized = 8,
    Namespace = 16,
    ExportContext = 32,
    ContainsThis = 64,
```

And I've seen such numeric constants in other places too. What is the purpose of this?

My guess was that it is done to add some new items later somewhere between the existing ones. Especially after seeing this:

```
    ThisNodeHasError = 32768,
    JavaScriptFile = 65536,
    ThisNodeOrAnySubNodesHasError = 131072,
    HasAggregatedChildData = 262144,
    JSDoc = 1048576,
    BlockScoped = 3, // three?
```

But isn't it in this case easier to have numbers like 100, 200, 300 etc.

The other guess was that it has something to do with bitwise operations, but I am not sure at all after I saw `3`.

FWIW, the list ends up completely weirdly:

```
    ReachabilityCheckFlags = 384,
    ReachabilityAndEmitFlags = 1408,
    ContextFlags = 6387712,
    TypeExcludesFlags = 20480,
```

P.S. Probably exponential is not correct here (so I am sorry and you are welcomed to correct me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that this enum is used as a flags enum. These values can be combined using the bitwise or (`|`) operator. So you can have a value that is simultaneously both memebers of the enum

```
let x = NodeFlags.AwaitContext  | NodeFlags.ThisNodeHasError // The node is both an await context but also has errors
```

For this to work the values must not interfere with each other at a bit level, so each value must be a power of two (which will only have a single bit set to one at a different position for each power)

Basically each bit in the value is an independent flag. They could have gone with separate flags on the node such as `isLet`,  `isConst`, `isAwaitContext`,  `isError` etc, but that would have been wasteful in terms of memory and for a compiler that adds up since there are a lot of nodes. Like this a single field of 64 bits can represent 64 flags.

To extract which value is set you can use the `&` operator for example `x &  NodeFlags.ThisNodeHasError !== 0` would mean the ThisNodeHasError is set in the `x` variable.

Comment: Hi, Titian, it's been long time :-) I am sorry, I am a bit dumb about bitwise operations, I guessed it has something to do with them, but does the bitwise work with odd numbers like 3? I just don't know.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev `3` is `11` in binary, combining the flags for Let and Const.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev It works, but you have to think about it in binary a bit. For example `0001` is let `0010` is `const` if you or them bitwise, you get `0011` which is 3, so a value of 3 would mean the node is both let and const.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev basically each bit in the value is an independent flag. They could have gone with flags on node such as `islet` `isConst` `isAwaitContext` `isError` etc, but that would have been wasteful in terms of memory and for a compiler that adds up since there are a lot of nodes. Better use a single int to represent all of them (up to 64 flags in a single value)

Comment: Titian, great explanation thank you! The others a good too, but you were first to answer and the explanation is so simple. Your explanation made it click for me, so any key is either 1 or 10 or 100 or 1000 and the two first keys combined is 11 which is 3 in decimal system. So simple it hurts.

Answer (score 2):

These are all powers of two, so in binary, you'd have

```
None = 0b0,
Let = 0b1,
Const = 0b10,
NestedNamespace = 0b100,
Synthesized = 0b1000,
Namespace = 0b10000,
```

And so on. This makes it possible to combine the flags, for example `111` means `Let, Const, NestedNamespace`

In your case `ReachabilityCheckFlags = 384` is `0b110000000` in binary, so it combines the flags with values `128` (`0b10000000`) and `256` (`0b100000000`)

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev the first defines all the *single* elements, and `3` combines two of the single elements to form a bitmask for both Let and Const. You can have any bitmask but if it contains more than one `1` digit in binary, it means it's a combination. In general, that means it's also not a power of two (in decimal).

Comment: Thank you VLAZ. I've upvoted your question, but accepted another one because it was simpler for me. But, could you please explain why you put `b` before `1`s? I've never seen this way of writing binary, usually it looked 001, 010, 100  etc

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev oh, it's just how binary is noted in JS. Also, some other languages but I was using the JS notation. If you type in `console.log(0b101)` in JS it would would get `5` printed. I thought it'd be clearer because it gets confusing if you talk about `10` and `10` and one is decimal, the other is binary.

Comment: Haha indeed. Didn't know that because never used it in JS (or elsewhere). Thank you very much, and let the day be good for you! :-)

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev we all learn, that's why we're here right? :)

Answer (score 2):

With a combined flag, you could get the enum types by checking the values with a [bitwise AND `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND).

This works in the other direction as well where you could just add all flags with [bitwise OR `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR)

```js
const getFlags = value => Object.keys(nodeFlags).filter(k => nodeFlags[k] & value);

var nodeFlags = { None: 0, Let: 1, Const: 2, NestedNamespace: 4, Synthesized: 8, Namespace: 16, ExportContext: 32, ContainsThis: 64 },
    blockScoped = 3,
    flagsOfBlockScoped = getFlags(blockScoped);
    
console.log(flagsOfBlockScoped);
```