# What is "personastateflags"?

Tags: node.js, steam, steam-web-api

I requesting this endpoint `https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXX&steamids=76561198049710886`

And I'm getting this reply:

```
{ 
  "response":{ 
    "players":[ 
      { 
        "steamid":"76561198049710886",
        "communityvisibilitystate":3,
        "profilestate":1,
        "personaname":"testing",
        "lastlogoff":1570961241,
        "profileurl":"https://steamcommunity.com/id/danpool/",
        "avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/1b/1b5db030143e6110de8558adf4235ece591ddde1.jpg",
        "avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/1b/1b5db030143e6110de8558adf4235ece591ddde1_medium.jpg",
        "avatarfull":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/1b/1b5db030143e6110de8558adf4235ece591ddde1_full.jpg",
        "personastate":0,
        "realname":"John Doe",
        "primaryclanid":"103582791429521408",
        "timecreated":1317282093,
        "personastateflags":0,
        "loccountrycode":"NO"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But i'm confused what `personastateflags` means, I find some stuff by searching for it but they all different and official docs don't have any information about it.

last one i found is this one:

```
  1: 'Offline', 2: 'Online', 4: 'Golden',
  64: 'Online using Big Picture',
  256: 'Online using Web Client',
  512: 'Online using Mobile',
  1024: 'Online using Steam Controller'
```

but `personastateflags` is `0` in most cases so it doesn't make any sense :/

I also tried to launching big picture mode while I was online, and result was "1024" which would be "Online using Steam Controller" and not correct.

P.S.

I successfully converted `personastate` using this object

```js
   0: 'Offline', 1: 'Online', 2: 'Busy',
   3: 'Away', 4: 'Snooze', 5 :'Looking to Trade',
   6: 'Looking to Play'
```

Comment: These would be bit masks. You can combine several flags into one field using those. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162652/why-exponential-enum-keys-are-used-here/) which also deals with the same concept.

Comment: @VLAZ I know how to do it in js, my problem is I don't know what `personastateflags` is, there no docs for it

Comment: It shows you whether a person is online, offline, in Big Picture mode, using the mobile client, etc. It's self-descriptive.

Comment: @VLAZ I am missing something? how do I know which is which? like can you tell me what is `personastateflags` = `0` means? is it `online` is it `online using web browser`

Comment: There are no flags set, hence it's zero. Why exactly no flags are being sent is a different matter - probably for privacy reasons. But whatever the reason, when you have a bit flags, zero means no flags. How else are you going to represent no bit flags set?

Comment: @VLAZ for example api returns `"personastate": 0` and I convert it to `status: 'Offline'`

Comment: Again, `0` means no flags are sent. It's not "offline" but literally "none of the known flags". So, you could call it "unknown".

Comment: Again, what if it's not `0`? what are other possible outputs? and how do I convert them.

Comment: OK, you said you knew how bit flags work but seems you don't. I urge you to visit the other question, as it explains how big flags work. But basically, you have one or more of the flags in a single number field. If you convert the field to binary, you'd get `1000010` (decimal `66` ) which is "Online" + "in Big Picture mode". `1000000` is `64` (the big picture mode flag) and `10` is `2` (the online flag). You have to test the value against bit masks to check which are on - `field & bitmask` will result in `0` if the given mask (flag) is not present and non-zero if it is.

Comment: @VLAZ I get how it's works, when I was online in steam my `personastateflags` was `0` when I launch big picture mode, and my `personastateflags` was `1024` which doesn't make sense if using this object I provided in my question, because it would be `Online using Steam Controller`

Answer (score 0):

I have not read into steam docs, but it should mean that the user is offline.

Comment: No, offline is `1`. Zero means none of the flags.

Comment: 0 Must mean that you do not have access to see the profile's current activity state.

Comment: @Hobey823 I was checking my own profile as well, when I was online it returned `0`, then I launch big picture mode and it was `1024`, what I'm looking for is official correct reference.

Comment: @Hobey823 no, every privacy settings is "public"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what docs say:

The user's current status. 0 - Offline, 1 - Online, 2 - Busy, 3 - Away, 4 - Snooze, 5 - looking to trade, 6 - looking to play. If the player's profile is private, this will always be "0", except is the user has set their status to looking to trade or looking to play, because a bug makes those status appear even if the profile is private.